# Independent solution means no repeated root.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y_1 $ and $y_2 $ are independent  solution of homogeneous second order linear differential equation.Then

1. neither $y_1$ and nor $y_2$ has repeated zeros ?
2. They don't have common point of extremum.

I don't see why its true. I tried  write it as linear combination in non trivial way but have no clue how to use hypothesis ( i will add more details if i found any) .please give me a hint to start with

Answer (score 1):

If a "repeated zero" of $y_1$ is a point $x_0$ such that $y_1(x_0)=y_1'(x_0)=0$, then (1) is clear: Uniquenss for the IVP $ay''+by'+cy=0$, $y(x_0)=0$, $y'(x_0)=0$ shows that $y_1=0$, so $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not independent. Similarly for (2): If $y_1'(x_0)=y_2'(x_0)=0$ you can use uniqueness to show that $y_2$ is a multiple of $y_1$.

Comment: for 2) how to use uniqueness, itsn't obvious for me